# How to move a container View in Swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, swift2, uipangesturerecognizer, uicontainerview

How to move a container View in Swift
I'm working on an app that will be just for iPad, and because of the size I am using containers to embed other views. In this app, I need to move a viewController that is within a container.

For example, I created a ViewController and put a Container View. **I must use the UIPanGesture in the label, and drag your finger across the screen, move the ContainerView in ViewControler Initial**.

[image]

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container view is just a normal `UIView`.

Just create a view outlet to your View Controller if you want to move the view using it's frame.

[You probably know how to create an outlet connection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_connections/chapters/CreatingOutlet.html) ?

You can also use Auto Layout and created outlets to your constraints and change their value.

Comment: I need to move the Container View the first ViewController.

Comment: Yes I know. That's how you do it. Just trust me :) Ctrl+Click and and create an outlet connection.

Comment: I tried to do that, but when I create an outlet, nothing happens, Xcode prevents the creation of the outlet in a direferente the view associated with it.
I tried to create an outlet of view (first ViewController) in segunta view (embed in ContainerView).